# For loop prints None

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list with tuples:

```
my_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

When I want to print each list item using an **inline for loop**:

```
[print(i) for i in my_list]
```

I get:

```
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
('c', 3)
[None, None, None]
```

Why does the output also contains the [None, ...] statement?

Comment: because `print(i)` returns `None`

Comment: If you want to print the list just do `print([i for i in my_list])`
`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I use `print([i for i in my_list])` I get `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`, but not a row-by-row print? Note: I use Python 3.x and Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki why? Your list comp is the same as simply deferferencing the list via `print(*my_list)`. Decomposing the list with a newline seperator will do the trick: `print(*my_list,sep="\n")` - see answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the interactive [Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html) which will invoke the `print(i)` expression during evaluation and which is why you get the first part of the output:

```
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
('c', 3)
```

Furthermore, the result of calling `print(i)` (that is the value you get when you evaluate the expression `print(i)`) is `None` and since you are using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) the value of the expression which you passed to the interpreter is `[None, None, None]`. As usual the interpreter prints the value of the expression you entered, which explains the last line:

```
[None, None, None]
```

If you had executed your expression as a script you would have gotten your expected output:

```
% cat ./1.py
#!/usr/bin/python3

[print(i) for i in range(1, 3)]
% ./1.py
1
2
```

Note that this is *not* an *inline for loop*, there is no such thing as far as I can tell. Instead it is called list comprehension and is a special syntax to build lists.

If you are in the interpreter and want a single line for loop you can try:

```
for i in range(3): print(i)
```

but you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your [None,None,None] stems from the output generated by `print` - print returns None 
and the sideeffects of putting 3 print statements inside a list (and outputting theire parts), the resulting list is `[None,None,None]` wich is autoprited by your interpreter.

IMHO it would be better to deconstruct the list and use a fitting `sep`erator:

```
my_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

print(*my_list,sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
('c', 3)
```